# Massive excel columns - Isolating unique SKU ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, inventory-management

I have 2 large columns in excel with each column representing a SKU ID. 
Column A is the Old List found on our web site.
Column B is the new list

I need a formula that will allow me to see what SKU ID are not found in the new list so we can then delete them from the pile.

Any help will be great. I am racking my head trying to solve this.

Phil

Comment: What's wrong with MATCH() ?

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, this is just one of many options:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A, 0))), "FOUND", "NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Most helpful

Answer (score 1):

Or with Countif(), which will be faster than the exact Match wrapped in IsError:

```
=if(Countif(A:A,B1),"found","not found")
```

If you sort by column A, Match can be fast, too, using an approximate match.

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,1))=B1,"found","not found")
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Most helpful!!

Comment: @TheNoc Please mark the post that helped you as the answer as described in the [Tour]. That's how you can say thanks here.